# How to change a dataframe column from list value to multiple columns in r?

Tags: r, list, dataframe

```
This is my dataframe df:

    A                 B                            C
1   14      list('one'=1,'two'=3,'three'=98)     1.12
2   1       list('one'=8,'two'=87,'three'45)     0.98
3   81      list('one'=4,'two'=41,'three'19)     1.02
4   11      list('one'=4,'two'=0 ,'three'0 )     1.15
5   10      list('one'=1,'two'=1 ,'three'12)     0.80
```

I want the 'B' column which is a list to be splitted in different columns
and the new columns' names should contain the old column name + the lists' names.

```
The output should be like this:

    A     B.one  B.two  B.three  C
1   14      1     3       98     1.12
2   1       8     87      45     0.98
3   81      4     41      19     1.02
4   11      4     0       0      1.15
5   10      1     1       12     0.80
'
```

Comment: Could you please make the input copy/pasteable? `dput()` is a good function for that. `dput(df)` will make a copy/pasteable version of your data frame.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `tidyr::unnest_wider`. Example:

```
df = data.frame(a = 1:3)
df$b = list(list(x = 1, y = 2), list(x = 2, y = 5), list(x = 3, y = 4))
df
#   a    b
# 1 1 1, 2
# 2 2 2, 5
# 3 3 3, 4

tidyr::unnest_wider(df, b, names_sep = ".")
# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#       a   b.x   b.y
#   <int> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     1     2
# 2     2     2     5
# 3     3     3     4
```